# How install cuML module?

Tags: python, installation, pip, cuml

I launched this command in my jupyter notebook

```
pip install cuml
```

and I have this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cuml (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cuml
```

How can I solve it?

I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: Which OS and python version are you using?

Comment: windows 10 and python 3.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, cuml doesn't support windows OS at the moment. But you can try it on cloud for free.

Kaggle kernels: https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/rapids-gpu-knn-mnist-0-97

Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rY7Ln6rEE1pOlfSHCYOVaqt8OvDO35J0#forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true

Answer (score 1):

You can also use docker command to pull an image with RAPIDS library suite already installed.

Example:

```
docker pull rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda10.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04

docker run --runtime nvidia --rm -it -p 8888:8888 -p 8787:8787 -p 8786:8786 \
    rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda10.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04
```

More details: https://rapids.ai/start.html

Comment: This user showed no understanding of docker nor is there any discussion of RAPIDS. You should request more information from the user who posted the question.